# Regression problem as predicting a delta from another algorithm's output

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, regression, linear-regression

Suppose I have a supervised machine learning regression problem to predict a value that's supposed to improve upon an already-existing algorithm. I am trying to predict the distance that a small rocket will travel.

We currently have an algorithm that uses ballistic trajectory equations that produces a value called `physics_distance_in_km`, and we measure RMSE against the `true_distance` label in a test set.

We wanted to create a more accurate estimate for how far the small rocket will travel, so we formed a regression problem, added more features, and built models using OLS regression, random forest regression, neural network, etc. We are using `physics_distance_in_km` as a feature along with `wind_speed`, `air_density`, `propellant_type`, etc.

We found that while our machine learning regression algorithm improves our RMSE slightly on average, sometimes it is quite far off from the true distance and `physics_distance_in_km`. As one rare example, the rocket went 15 km, `physics_distance_in_km` predicted 12 km, but our regression output predicted 29 km, which is possible due to the regression not having a bound.

Instead of using `physics_distance_in_km` as a feature in our model, should we instead leave it out? Instead of the distance as a label, we could use `delta_distance` as the label computed as `true_distance` - `physics_distance_in_km`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In machine learning terms, you are composing models, or building an _ensemble_. Boosting, for example, forms a linear combination of predictors that minimize the error in a greedy fashion.

Answer (score 1):

I think predicting model *error* (`delta_distance`) makes a lot of sense and is worth trying. Since it's reasonable to expect that the error is a function of the overall rocket distance, I would keep `physics_distance_in_km` as an input to the error-prediction model.

Regarding outliers...I suspect that's a function of your model type. It's difficult to say without more details of what you did.